# WPF DataGrid and binding to rows data context

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

We looked into using the out of the box validation with the wpf datagrid but found it didn't give us enough control over how the validation worked.  Namely we didn't want a field to show as invalid until the user clicks the save button or edits that field.  We were able to get this to work with textbox and checkbox with a solution we are happy with.  We believe it will work for datagrdi as long as we can get access to the object a row is bound to.  However, we haven't been able to get the object through binding.

I've attached the relevant parts of the code to reproduce the sample.  The ObjectToValidate property on the ValidationContext class is what we would like to bind the row object to.  If you were wire up the code below run it and then edit one of the cells in the Name column you will get the exception in the ValidateMethod of the PropertyValidation class.

Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <behaviors:PropertyValidation PropertyName="Name">
                                <behaviors:PropertyValidation.Context>
                                    <behaviors:ValidationContext ObjectToValidate="{Binding}"/>
                                </behaviors:PropertyValidation.Context>
                            </behaviors:PropertyValidation>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Windows Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeMyItems();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void InitializeMyItems()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Age = i, Name = "Name" + i.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

PropertyValidation Class

```
public class PropertyValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public ValidationContext Context { get; set; }
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (Context.ObjectToValidate == null) throw new Exception("The validation object is null.");

        return new ValidationResult(true, "");
    }
}
```

ValidationContext Class

```
public class ValidationContext : DependencyObject
{

    public object ObjectToValidate
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ObjectToValidateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ObjectToValidateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ObjectToValidate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectToValidateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ObjectToValidate", typeof(object), typeof(ValidationContext), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: We were running into issues using the out of the box validation because the fields would validate before we were ready for them to.  We have fixed this for everything but the grid.  It also just gave us more granular control over when and how validation happens.  Tying it into the grid is the only thing we got left and if I can just get access to the object the row is bound to which would be our model in this case we would be fine.

Comment: I was trying to solve the same problem and ended up with a very similar solution. The problem is that the `Context` equivalent of my code is always `null` when `Validate` is called. How do I fix this? Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find this, but it is just the binding:

```
<behaviors:ValidationContext ObjectToValidate="{Binding}"/>
```

{Binding} usually represents the object that is bound at the certain row.

**Edit**

Can you use the IDataErrorInfo interface on the MyItem class?

```
public class MyItem : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;

                if (name == "Name")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                    {
                        result = "Name must be specified.";
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then the XAML would look like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule/>
                   </DataGridTextColumn.Binding.ValidationRules>
               </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply josh but this still isn't working for me.  The object is still coming back as null.  I'll try and get more code posted today.

Comment: I've updated my code sample to include all the necessary parts.